# Graph omitted and indented when using %matplotlib notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am plotting graphs in `Jupyter Notebook` using `matplotlib` package. 
Here is my code snippet:

```
%matplotlib notebook 
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(40,8))

freq_series = pd.Series.from_array(count_axis)
ax = freq_series.plot(kind='bar')
ax.set_xlabel("Tags")
ax.set_ylabel("Count")

plt.bar(range(len(count_axis)), count_axis, align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(name_axis)), name_axis, size=16, rotation=90)

rects = ax.patches

for rect, count in zip(rects, count_axis):
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2, height + 5, count, ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

If X-axis label text is too long, it gets omitted/cutaway like this and also, graph has weird left indent on default:

[image]

How can I fix this? (its zoomed because of using `%matplotlib notebook`). 
When I use `%matplotlib inline` X-axis is not omitted and there is no indent but I cannot zoom the graph and I need this feature.

**EDIT:** ok, so indent is because of line `plt.figure(figsize=(40,8))` where I set width statically to 40. But I still dont know how to get rid of that x-axis omitting.

Comment: You can call `plt.tight_layout()` just before calling `plt.show()` and those problems will be fixed. (At least they were for me). There are probably other ways to fix it (using stuff like `gridspec`), but those are overkill for the example.

Comment: Nice! I think you cant post this as an aswer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With most basic layouts, `tight_layout` will get everything onto the page. When I tried this in the `jupyter notebook`, the weird indent was also removed.

```
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```